# Making rectangle look like curved page

Tags: c#, winforms, image, graphics, picturebox

A little goofy to explain, but I think you'll get it.

Have you noticed how when you lay a book down on a table and open it, that its pages are curved a little - maybe along some kind of variable sine-like curve?

Is there some reasonably-easy way to emulate this effect with an image in a pictureBox?  I know the pictureBox has to be a rectangle, but I have seen a few things before about being able to transform the image.

Can you transform it by moving each pixel to a new location by using a formula ( like x = 1/4 sin(y) ) and getting the image (a page in a book) to have the curve to it?  If so, does the re-arrangement happen fast enough to where there is no waiting?

Comment: I don't understand... you want plot math function?

Comment: No.  I want to transform an image's pixels to provide a wavy curvature to it.  Look at the following link at the book pages and how they have a curve to the text.  Let's say I have an image of a PDF file.  It is rectangular.  I want to run all the pixels through a formula to relocate each pixel so that the image is transformed with a curve to it.  http://depositphotos.com/4651315/stock-illustration-Open-book.html

Comment: Sorry but it's not possible with picturebox control. You can rounded the picturebox but you cannot change the struct of the obj. If you want do this you must create a new obj control. But why you want do this?

Comment: I do not want to do this to the pictureBox control.  I want to do it to the image.  Why I want to do this?  Because, I want to render a page that looks like it is a page in an open book - not just a flat rectangle.  Graphics has scale, translate, rotate, etc.  I suspect the answer has something to do with a translate where the translation is on each pixel and is DIFFERENT for each pixel.  In other words, translate each pixel along a curve - not just a fixed X and Y.

Comment: I do see that you can use Matrix for storing information to be applied to transforms.  If you could put, for example, y = sin(x) in the matrix, you'd get a curve when you multiply against it.  Throw all the pixels into the matrix, and their translations will be on the curve.  Make sense?